# Create New Record Window Blank

Tags: record, create-records, new

I am a Salesforce Admin and I am trying to create a new record from a related list on the the Opportunity Object. I have FLS on all fields on both objects. It works on one app but not the other. I checked APP permissions and they are both identical and the custom object called Listing does not have any record types. Not sure what else to try. Please help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Patrick,

The issue is likely due to a dynamic forms misconfiguration. The 'new' form takes its orders from the dynamic fields component on the Lightning Record Page, if there is one, instead of using the traditional Page Layout. So if you have a Dynamics Fields component that is conditionally hidden, the new form will show up blank.

See the [Dynamic Forms Tips](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_considerations.htm&type=5) and this [Trailblazer Community](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A97NUSAZ) Question.